# Can't edit or delete groups in Contacts.app

Tags: macos, contacts

I'd like to delete a contact group or remove a person within one in Contacts.app and can't

The contextual and top menus doesn't have any commands for this, and the <kbd>delete</kbd> key does nothing. I *can* create new groups. I can't add contacts to old groups. I can remove a contact from a new group that I've recently added to it, but I cannot remove contacts from old groups.

How can I delete or edit these problem groups?

[image: Contextual menu for a group][image: Cannot remove some contacts from a group]

I'm syncing Google Contacts to Contacts.app as my primary source of contacts, and iCloud contacts are disabled. I'm not trying to sync Google's contact labels with Contacts.app.

Answer (score 0):

Enable iCloud contacts, even if you don't use them.

You need to have iCloud enabled for groups to be able to modify groups at all—even if you're not using iCloud as your primary means for storing contacts.

My theory is that Apple doesn't use Google's contacts API to sync group information, so it needs iCloud to tack group functionality onto Google-synced contacts.

——

**Update:** This isn't a true fix. It's made it so some contacts can be removed from groups and so some groups can be deleted, but it's unpredictable and incomplete.